# CSS animation spinner is intterrupted in IE Edge but works smooth on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code:

```css
.spinner-container {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 2;
}

.spinner-container .path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1,150; 
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: rgba(27, 154, 89, 0.7);
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1,150;  
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90,150; 
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;   
  }
  
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90,150; 
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;  
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1,150;  
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90,150; 
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;   
  }
  
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90,150; 
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;  
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="spinner-container" viewBox="0 0 44 44" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><circle class="path" cx="22" cy="22" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="4"></circle></svg>
```

If you run it in IE Edge, you will see that animation is interrupted. How can be fixed ?

Comment: IE and Opera don't honor CSS transforms at all on SVG elements. Instead, you must assign the value to the transform attribute.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/135-three-ways-animate-svg/ try this